# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ripser', after installing that package with terminal (and works on terminal)

Tags: python, macos, installation, pycharm

Trying to get ripser on pycharm.
Can't installed on "preferences>Python interpreter" cause:

> 40:537: execution error: WARNING: The directory '/Users/federicolot/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

So i manage to install the package on terminal with: sudo -H pip install ripser
working on pycharm terminal the python scripts works and correctly import ripser, but running the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ripser import ripser
from persim import plot_diagrams

data = np.random.random((100, 2))
diagrams = ripser(data)['dgms']
plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])
plt.figure(2)
plot_diagrams(diagrams, show=True)
```

it follow the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ripser'
and in the preference > Python interpreter list of packages there isn't ripser, while it appear in the pip list. why?

Comment: did you check on your environment that you are working on?

Comment: @Pygirl yep, its the same chosen as python interpreter for the project